# Grid and axes have disappeared. They apper briefly on New, then vanish

Tags: modeling, objects, interface

strong text[image: VIewport in Layout mode]

I was using Blender today, with the axes and grid showing as always on my default settings.
Then I went on to work in another window, and came back wanting to do a new design (in layout, for 3d printing, as usual).
I pressed Ctrl-N, General. The default cube appeared, the axes and grid briefly flashed into view and then vanished.
On pressing 1,3,5 or 7 there is no change to the lack of Overlays.
I searched the internet for an hour, finding mostly comments about changes to scale, and Viewport overlays, but mine seem OK in the picture below, although the ticked box where it says, "Grid" seems greyed out, as if that setting is not able to exert its effect.
I have never seen this before, and can't find an explanation anywhere.
Can anyone please give me an idea how to get my axes and grid back?
Many thanks for your help out there - I have asked before when totally stumped, and you've come good - I hope you can do it again.
Cheers,
PJF
PS
For reasons I don't understand at all, the overlays have now appeared but only in a restricted area. They now start at the bottom of the screen at 6 o'clock, and extend to the left only as far as 4.30. But the "Grid" is no longer greyed out.

All completely new to me, this lot!

[image]

Comment: looks like an error in your graphics card driver.  This is common with AMD devices but sometimes happens with NVidia or Intel.  Make sure your OS and card drivers are up to date.  If you're using Nvida, the Studio drivers tend to be more stable for Blender than the gaming drivers.

Comment: I suppose you've already checked the Clip Start and Clip End?